# What's the difference between ListView and GestureListView?

Tags: delphi, pascal

What's the difference between ListView and GestureListView? Examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the [TListview](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TListView) is a VCL control, based in the windows `listview`, this component is for general use and supports different visualizations (styles) like report style, lists, small icons, etc.

[image]

by the other hand the [`TGestureListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/GestureCtrls.TGestureListView) is  a [`TCustomListView`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomListView) descendant which was made to display the name of gestures and a small thumbnail with the gesture’s shape.

[image]